# Python message to server yield so response

Tags: sockets, python-3.x

I haven't played with python in a while so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I made a simple script that sends a message to a given server over a certain port. However any messages given, even HTML commands, returns absolutely nothing.

Here's a code snippet that reproduces the issue:

```
  #!/usr/bin/env python
  import socket  


  TCP_IP = 'www.google.ca'
  TCP_PORT = 80
  BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
  MESSAGE = "pls work".encode("utf-8")
  s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,   socket.SOCK_STREAM)
  s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
  s.send(MESSAGE)
  data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
  s.close()
  print(data)
```

I wanna know if something changed that I am unaware of about the socket library, since I'm not even getting error responses from servers.

Comment: Its possible google's servers wont respond to arbitrary messages. You'd be better off testing by sending the messages to your own machine. You can use `nc` to bind to arbitrary ports for easy testing

Comment: Possible I suppose. However I'm on my android device and I'm not sure netcat is a thing there.

Comment: Are you on a local network on which you have a machine that has netcat? It doesn't need to be the same device. My point is use something you have complete control over because you're relying on possible unpredictable behavior of a google server.

Comment: I tested the program out on the linux computer and well the message sends but doesn't come back.

Comment: How do you know it sent? In order to receive something, you would need a server on the other side that will respond. Netcat wont automatically send a response unless you tell it to